# jquery get element id when click on page using 'this' does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the id of what ever element on a page when the user clicks on the page.  There are several posts on here that show using 'this' works, but my code does not work with 'this'.  The id returned is undefined.  But I use the 'event' technique and it works.

Can someone explain the differences?

```
$(function(){

//document or 'body' tags both don't work

$('body').click(function(){

    //var id = event.target.id;
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    alert (id);
//returned undefined


});

      });
```

This code works

```
$(function(){

$('body').click(function(event){

    var id = event.target.id;
    //var id=$(this).attr('id');
    alert (id);



});});
```

Comment: Because *this* will be the element that the listener is attached to (the body) and you likely haven't given it an id. The event target is the element that the event originally occured on, which is not necessarily the one calling the listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the function below, the variable `id` will refer to the `body` element's `id` itself.

```
$('body').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id); // Will alert "undefined" if the <body> tag has no id
});
```

Using a different function like the one below actually does what you want by using `event.target`, which is the element that is actually clicked within the `body` element:

```
$('body').click(function(event) {    
    var id = event.target.id;
    alert(id); // Will alert the id if the element has one    
});
```

So, in short: `event.target` is the element that is clicked, `$(this)` would refer to the `<body>` tag.

Comment: thanks shaz, but what about using $(document).click? it does not work either.

Comment: @Jamex It seems to work fine for me; take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YqTJZ/ What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get the id of the element that I clicked.  But I guess that 'document' refers to the document itself instead of the element.  I guess I am having a hard time separating the syntax since I just got started with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is getting the body element id whereas the second one is getting the id of the element in the body that received the click event